# What explains the lack of concern toward the unusual devices and phenomena?

Tags: tales-from-the-loop

Around the Loop, there are various objects with unusual properties. Most of these are **extraordinarily dangerous**, like a machine that can stop time or a sphere that will switch whoever goes inside with the nearest person. They are easy enough to find: after all, even teenagers can find them lying around. Some of them, like the homicidal robot from the final episode, probably will even seek people out. It's not clear where all of them come from. However, whatever the provenance of these devices, no one from the Loop appears to make an effort to prevent people from finding and using them, even though it seems that Russ and the managers of the Loop are broadly aware of them (i.e. the Echo Sphere).

Moreover, there are even natural phenomena like the stream. To judge from some of Loretta's dialogue in the final episode, she knows that the stream is a permanent time phenomenon when running, yet Cole and Jakob did not seem to know to stay away from it.

Nor is the harm caused by all these things purely hypothetical: we see that various people have horrifying experiences, or even suffer permanent side effects up to and including death, as a direct result of contact with these phenomena.

In short, the managers of the Loop, and the town in general, seem oddly blase about the possible harm caused by all the odd objects and locations lying about. Why is this?